# Curl returns a null string and curl_error also returns null

Tags: php, curl

The code i've used is

```
            $request = 'sales='.$_slots['sales']['value'].'&duration='.$_slots['duration']['value'];
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
            curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            $result = curl_exec($ch );
            $response = explode(chr(10),$result);
            $data = implode('', $response);
            $error = curl_error($ch)
            curl_close( $ch );
```

The `curl_error` also returns `null` so I have no way to track why its not working. The `$url` is defined above and is a valid url.I also tried without sending any post but still it does not work.

Any advice would be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: where is curl_error() code in your question? also what is your url?

Comment: Also is your `$request` variable properly URL encoded, there is a function `http_build_query()` for that

Comment: i had used the curl_error but i removed it since it returns null

Comment: I also tried removing all post but still no luck

Comment: @Peter yes it is . I echoed it and checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, curl was only showing this behavior on https URLs, whether `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` are set to false for testing, or not, just as you have here.

I had recently run a `yum update` which updated [Name Service Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch), which was the only change to the server I could think of. I updated via yum on another server, and that server started to show the same failure in curl.

**Restarting the Apache service resolved the issue.** Https URLs worked in curl after this restart.

I did find examples of curl/ssl/nss errors occurring in the past, but in my case never saw an error message.

- https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2015-09/0019.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280548/curl-doesnt-connect-to-https-while-wget-does-nss-error-12286
- [CURL (35) SSL connect error / NSS error -5961](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128791/curl-35-ssl-connect-error-nss-error-5961)

This isn't a very satisfying resolution because I don't feel like I have a full picture of why this failure occurred, so I will continue to investigate and add an update if I find something more.

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar the point is, an update caused a problem with Apache that required it to be restarted, as soon as the update was applied. What was your resolution?