# CURL (35) SSL connect error / NSS error -5961

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, centos

OS: `CentOS release 6.9 (Final)`

CURL: `curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.`4.2

Hello,

I have a host which I am trying to run a curl command from, for testing only

```
curl https://api.twitter.com/ -v
```

Returns the below

```
* About to connect() to api.twitter.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 104.244.42.2... connected
* Connected to api.twitter.com (104.244.42.2) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5961
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

After some lengthy reading I have come to the conclusion this is possibly a SLL issue due to either my OS version or CURL version, or both!

First question would be is that right? Are there indeed known issues with this configuration?

Second, can I build from source a working combination? I am unable to update my OS due to legacy dependencies

Comment: Please check with other tools like `openssl s_client` if you can reach the target host from the same machine. Error -5961 means connection reset by peer which might indicate a problem at the server end or some middleware or firewall blocking the access. See https://superuser.com/questions/916077/what-is-nss-error-5961-pr-connect-reset-error

Comment: With open ssl I was getting a similar error until I specified the domain -servername by IP and not hostname and it worked.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that it worked in `openssl s_client` with `-servername some-ip-address` and not with  `-servername api.twitter.com` ? How about without `-servername` argument?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Rebuild a fresh server running centos 7

Worked straight away no issues!

Answer (score 2):

Try with specific ssl/tls or cipher suits for example: `curl --tlsv1.2 https://api.twitter.com/`

Answer (score 0):

Since you say this is for testing only, you could try `-k` to connect insecurely:

```
curl -k https://api.twitter.com/
```

Or, if you think it’s an outdated SSL cert bundle you could download a newer certificate and trust store from the internet and try that by using the `--cert` and `--cacert` options

Comment: Tried that brother, still the same (curl: (35) SSL connect error)

Comment: Interesting, when I get back to my desk I will fiddle with this

Comment: Much appreciated, i do suspect issues with my versions, I am looking to compile from source curl version 7.57. Working on that now